# Why is Windows Security Log using different formats on machines that seem to be the same?

Tags: windows, windows-event-log

I have a group of like computers (Win 7) that I'm working on creating some event monitoring rules around but I noticed something odd about what I'm receiving.

One machine in the group is returning very verbose log messages:

```
<13>Mar 24 13:42:21 MACHINE123 AgentDevice=WindowsLog    AgentLogFile=Security    PluginVersion=7.1.4.698761    Source=Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing    Computer=MACHINE123.SOMECORP.Local    User=    Domain=    EventID=4648    EventIDCode=4648    EventType=8    EventCategory=12544    RecordNumber=487779    TimeGenerated=1427218938    TimeWritten=1427218938    Level=0    Keywords=0    Task=0    Opcode=0    Message=A logon was attempted using explicit credentials.  Subject:  Security ID:  SOMECORP\UserA  Account Name:  usera  Account Domain:  SOMECORP  Logon ID:  0x1234567  Logon GUID:  {AAAAAAAA-FFFF-E6AB-3B67-FE7473A02CE9}  Account Whose Credentials Were Used:  Account Name:  A.User@SomeCorp.com  Account Domain:  SOMECORP  Logon GUID:  {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}  Target Server:  Target Server Name: EXCHANGE.SOMECORP.Local  Additional Information: EXCHANGE.SOMECORP.Local  Process Information:  Process ID:  0xa04  Process Name:  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\outlook.exe  Network Information:  Network Address: -  Port:   -  This event is generated when a process attempts to log on an account by explicitly specifying that account’s credentials.  This most commonly occurs in batch-type configurations such as scheduled tasks, or when using the RUNAS command.
```

However, the others are sending over a shortened version of the same event:

```
<13>Mar 24 14:33:32 MACHINE456 AgentDevice=WindowsLog    AgentLogFile=Security    PluginVersion=7.1.4.698761    Source=Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing    Computer=MACHINE456.SOMECORP.Local    User=    Domain=    EventID=4648    EventIDCode=4648    EventType=8    EventCategory=12544    RecordNumber=505638    TimeGenerated=1427222009    TimeWritten=1427222009    Level=0    Keywords=0    Task=0    Opcode=0    Message=SOMECORP\UserB USERB SOMECORP 0x7654321 {BBBBBBBB-EEEE-3CB9-D00A-A56E3F838596} B.User@somecorp.com SOMECORP {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} EXCHANGE.SOMECORP.Local EXCHANGE.SOMECORP.Local 0x1230 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\OUTLOOK.EXE - -
```

The problem I have is that my event processor isn't parsing the latter message because the field descriptors aren't in it. I'd prefer not to need to spend a bunch of time setting up a custom implementation of a parser that ought to work out of the box.

Why would the same event generate two very different looking log messages on different computers? Is there some configuration or policy option I should look at to see about getting those into the same format?

Comment: I suppose the first question would be which software you are using to forward those events. It looks like you are using some sort of syslog forwarder? Since Windows almost certainly logs it correctly, the issue would most likely be in your event log monitoring software.

Comment: Do the two machines have the same audit settings in place? You can view current settings with: auditpol /get /category:*